# In Laravel, is there a way to find out whether `firstOrCreate` created or if it found the row?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

In Laravel, is there a way to differentiate between `firstOrCreate` creating the row and if finding out the row exists from before?

Or will I have to manually do a `get()` first, and then create the row?

Comment: If exists it finds the data else it will create new data.

Comment: Yes, but I want to know if the data existed and it did nothing, or if it created the data.

Comment: `$test = Model::firstOrCreate()` just `print_r($test)` this will show the data.

Comment: It will help you to understand http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27877948/check-if-laravel-model-got-saved-or-query-got-executed

Comment: One more meanigful  resource http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25178464/first-or-create

Answer (score 127, accepted):

If you created the model in the current lifecycle, then the model's `wasRecentlyCreated` attribute will be set to `true`. Otherwise, that attribute will be set to `false`.

In other words, lets say you have a user with the email, `bob@example`.

```
$user = User::firstOrCreate(['email' => 'bob@example.com']);

// the below will dump out false because this entry already existed
var_dump($user->wasRecentlyCreated);
```

Now, lets say `new@example.com` doesn't exist.

```
$user2 = User::firstOrCreate(['email' => 'new@example.com']);

// the below will dump out true because this user was created
// in the current request lifecycle
var_dump($user2->wasRecentlyCreated);
```

Comment: That is delicious

Comment: Brilliant Laravel has everything already covered.